# Paypal express checkout L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm not showing in transaction details

Tags: paypal

I have successfully setup an express checkout process where I pass through a bunch of individual items with a title, price and description for each and can complete the transaction in sandbox mode. The issue is that the description doesn't show on the transaction details page for the merchant, yet it shows on the buyers checkout page.

I have read and re-read the doco and searched for solutions but can't seem to find an answer. Can anyone help?

Doco - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1):

Are you supplying all of your `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_*` and `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_*` variables in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call as well as your SetExpressCheckout call?

SetExpressCheckout will control what the buyer sees when they go to check out on PayPal.  DoExpressCheckoutPayment will control what the buyer is actually charged for, and what will show up in both the buyer's and merchant's PayPal accounts afterwards.  Therefore, if you want your item details to be included in the transaction, you need to make sure that it's included in both calls.